# Redirect to a different tomcat using struts

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

I have an html page deployed in one tomcat. When I click a link on the page, it takes me to a page deployed in another tomcat.

Now, I have to use struts to do this,

```
<action name="forward" class="xyz">
        <result>abc.jsp</result>
</action>
```

But if I use it like this, the new html file opens in same tomcat.